# Swift Terminated due to memory issue

Tags: ios, swift

I've noticed that after reloading the MapKit View in my app, the app crashes and I am given the error `Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue` I believe this is because I am initialising so many variables in `viewDidLoad()` such as:

```
    // LOCATIONS
    let windcoord: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-39.055961,174.072288)
    let bcoord: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-39.057487, 174.054154)
    let hatcoord: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-39.069150, 174.081657)
    let halocoord: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-39.058951, 174.073410)
    let rockcoord: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-39.010627, 174.178184)
    let pixelcoord: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-39.057265, 174.073791)
    let signcoord: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-39.058316, 174.051954)
    let wheelcoord: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-39.056593, 174.072684)
    let tukocoord: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-39.056812, 174.072730)
    let faeocoord: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-39.059038, 174.070527)
    let cloudcoord: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-39.059515,174.073706)
    let snakecoord:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-39.057154, 174.072670)
    let shinycoord:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-39.05602950741741, 174.0699454416841)
    let doncoord: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-39.009391, 174.178753)
    let anchorcoord: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-39.055985, 174.072476)
    let catcoord: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-39.066965, 174.079661)
    let colour_polecoord: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-39.057508,174.072513)
    let collection_coord:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-39.058208,174.070732)
```

Along with many others. I thought, however `viewDidLoad()` only ran once when the app first loaded the respective view? Could I maybe put these declarations in a seperate class and create an object of that class and just keep reference to it? Or is there an easier way to do this. Picture below shows Memory usage (spikes are from returning to MapKit View.)

[Memory Usage of app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaLRO.png)

Comment: no, the amount of variables is not the problem unless you create a few billion ones (which you do not, or do you?). The only cause is that you create some variables over and over again and store them in an array or map and never release / remove them. Or you have some retain cycles.

Comment: Yes this is what I mean, I am initialising two lists of Objects along with multiple other variables so when the MapView is reloaded again it creates the objects again and its impacting the memory.

Comment: I also don't understand why viewDidLoad() is running more than once. Is this run for every instance of the MapKit view? If so I only need it to run once and keep that object.

Comment: Any Ideas???????

Answer (score 0):

Fixed using a Unwind Segue [Used this for reference.](https://medium.com/@mimicatcodes/create-unwind-segues-in-swift-3-8793f7d23c6f)